# sequelize v5 using typescript, Type expected for model.d.ts file

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

This is the error message I am getting after upgrading to V5 from V4.

I can comment out the unknown part from the lib, and everything else runs just fine.

> node_modules/sequelize/types/lib/model.d.ts:108:29 - error TS1110:
>   Type expected.
>
> 108   method: string | [string, ...unknown[]];

This is my typical model definition:

```
interface IAllergenExtend extends Model {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  updatedAt?: string;
  createdAt?: string;
}

type AllergenModel = typeof Model &
  (new (values?: object, options?: BuildOptions) => IAllergenExtend) & {
    associate: (model: IDB) => any;
  };

const allergenFactory = (sequalize: Sequelize) => {
  const Allergen = (<AllergenModel>sequalize.define('Allergen', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    name: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.TEXT
    },
    description: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.TEXT
    }
  })) as AllergenModel;

  Allergen.associate = (model: IDB) => {
    Allergen.belongsToMany(model.Dish, {
      through: db.AllergenDish,
      foreignKey: 'allergenId',
      as: 'dishes'
    });
  };

  return Allergen;
};

export { allergenFactory, AllergenModel };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check you typescript version. I had to update to 4.27.34 to get past this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have Node 12.13.0 with TS Version 3.7.2 and i am receiving this error when using Sequelize 5.21.2